# How can avoid I withholding tax on global REITs

Tags: investing, united-kingdom

I only have UK REITs in an ISA at the moment.

Can I get exposure to other countries REITs directly or indirectly without withholding tax being taken at the source?

I want to increase diversification in this asset class to reduce risk, but also to be tax efficient to have good expected returns.

Comment: `without withholding tax being taken at the source` Why is that an issue ? Are(Will be) your withholding tax in millions of £ ?

Comment: @DumbCoder does it need to be millions of £ to make it worth considering?

Comment: @rdans I would think so. E.g. US. REIT dividend income is 30%. And I don't think they dish out high dividends. So unless and until your total dividend income is in high `000s` or in `millions` not sure how the OP assumes the withholding tax will affect him. If he shows a calculation of how it is affecting his returns that might be more easier.

Comment: I’m 27 and have been investing for 3 years with a long term outlook. I have 10k in uk REITs 10k in global growth stocks 10k in value stocks and 20k in saveing to be invested I currently save 12k a year and plan to invest most of it long term.

Comment: if I stay invested for 30 years and globule REITs offer say 4% then it’s 2.8% after %30 with holding tax and in 30 years it’s 1.028^30 = 2.3 vs 1.04^30 = 3.2 times and I would have made about 40% more all else being equal. (3.2-2.3)/2.3

Comment: Would have about 40% more rather than would have made. Would have made about 70% more 0.9/1.3 .  Fees and tax add up significantly over the long term.

Answer (score 1):

U.S. citizens can claim a U.S. tax credit for foreign tax withheld. So look for tax credits available in your country.

And here is a UK link:

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/calculating-foreign-tax-credit-relief-on-income-hs263-self-assessment-helpsheet/hs263-calculating-foreign-tax-credit-relief-on-income-2017
.